# How does the angular-fullstack run express as a deamon?

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, express, daemon

I'm deploying the starter project https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack (the most popular yeoman generator).  I've build and served the project on a remote ubuntu 14.01 server using the command:

```
 grunt serve:dist
```

Everything works great... until I terminate the ssh session.  Has anyone successfully run this generator project as a daemon? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nohup.

```
nohup  grunt serve:dist &
```

Check [nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) man page